# simple jquery didnt work, and returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple code to hide and show paragraph, and using jquery as the trigger

suddenly my jquery return errors,this is the error

```
    SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
http://localhost/portofolio1/navigation_test.php/jquery-2.1.3.js
Line 1

 ReferenceError: $ is not defined
http://localhost/portofolio1/navigation_test.php/
Line 9
```

if i use cdn it work perfectly as usual

this is my simple code to test my jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple list</title>
        <!--        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script>
            
            $(function () {

               $("p").click(function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
        <p>Click me away!</p>
        <p>Click me too!</p>

        <button onclick="">SHOW ALERT</button>


    </body>
</html>
```

> **SOLVED**
>
> after i create new .php file and move ALL the code to the new file, it
>   work normal, i dont know the problem, this sure really weird

Answer (score 1):

Mind the quotes:

```
<script src="./jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```

`type` is optional by the way.

Also check if `http://localhost/portofolio1/navigation_test.php/jquery-2.1.3.js` is pointing to jQuery. From the looks of your error, the script is pointing to  something *not* jQuery, possibly an error page, hence `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`. This error means that the browser expected a script, but returned HTML (signified by the script meeting an unexpected `<`).

Comment: if i remove <script src="./jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>, it return the second error which was line 9

Comment: @stacheldraht27 Check if that path actually points to your jQuery. The first error is caused by not providing a script to `<script>`. The second happens when the file was parsed as a script, but declared no `$` which means jQuery didn't load.

Comment: i put the jquery file in the same folder with my php file,

Comment: it work normal earlier, but suddenly when i run the code it return that error T T